# How do I add inventory items via ruby/heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, ruby

Currently, I am developing an app for purchasing food items. I have implemented stripe as a payment process using this as a guide: https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend

**the problem:** when using this method I simply clicked on the purple icon and proceeded to enter my info and created a backendUrl to be used for my app. All works except when it comes to processing the payment as my inventory items(located in firebase) are not able to be retrieved. Therefore, when placing order I get this in swift: "Failed to create a Payment Intent: unknown"

After getting this error I examined the logs in Heroku and came across this: *RuntimeError - Can't find price for Guacamole*

so it seems that the payment isn't going through because it can not retrieve the price for this item.

Now if you examine the web.rb file which is derived from the GitHub guide I used.

There is this:

```
# Our example apps sell emoji apparel; this hash lets us calculate the total amount to charge.
EMOJI_STORE = {


     "" => 2000,
      "" => 4000,
      "" => 3000,
      "" => 700,
      "" => 600,
      "" => 1000,
      "" => 2000,
      "" => 2500,
      "" => 800,
      "" => 3000,
      "" => 2000,
      "" => 5000,
      "" => 5500,
      "" => 6000,
      "" => 2000,
      "" => 2500,

}

def price_lookup(product)
  price = EMOJI_STORE[product]
  raise "Can't find price for %s (%s)" % [product, product.ord.to_s(16)] if price.nil?
  return price
end

def calculate_price(products, shipping)
  amount = 1099  # Default amount.

  if products
    amount = products.reduce(0) { | sum, product | sum + price_lookup(product) }
  end
```

**Finally** I figure I just add `"Guacamole" => 2000` to the list above and run it.

SADLY this did not work. I have no prior experience with ruby but when I applied the above to the list I still got the same error: *RuntimeError - Can't find price for Guacamole*

it may be something simple... but as of right now my hands are tied and despite several hours of searching and reading tutorials I am unable to successfully add my items so that I can successfully make a charge.

Comment: Hi @Aaron34, Welcome to Stack overflow.
If you are seeking help with your code then you should include a minimal reproducible example in your post. How does your method `calculate_price` gets called? How does the final code (including Guacamole) look like? 

Please read stackoverflow.com/help/asking and update your question with meaningful information.

Comment: @Sebastian okay! thanks for the tip I will do that here in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put some logs in this code to see whats comming in the request, like this.

```
def price_lookup(product)
  p product
  p EMOJI_STORE

  price = EMOJI_STORE[product]
  raise "Can't find price for %s (%s)" % [product, product.ord.to_s(16)] if price.nil?
  return price
end
```

Other thing is check if the code in heroku is updated the Guacamole in the list.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: jorgedjr21 thanks for the fast response. I implemented the above and I got this in my logs in heroku: 2020-03-30T15:50:16.038034+00:00 app[web.1]: "Guacamole "
2020-03-30T15:50:16.038051+00:00 app[web.1]: nil
2020-03-30T15:50:16.038357+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-03-30 15:50:16 - RuntimeError - Can't find price for Guacamole  (43):
2020-03-30T15:50:16.038359+00:00 app[web.1]:  web.rb:348:in `price_lookup'

Comment: so I got different result as opposed to what I was getting. By this I mean the first two lines that display "Guacamole" and nil. I am assuming nil is the price that it is not able to get.
I am editing the code on my end and using **git add .** git commit -m "updates" **  **git push heroku master** to upload it to heroku. Is this what you mean by checking if the code in heroku is updating the Guacamole in the list?

Comment: Yes @Aaron34 you are doing right updating heroku doing the git procedures.
The first line :

2020-03-30T15:50:16.038034+00:00 app[web.1]: "Guacamole " 

Is the product, so you are receiving. If you look, there is a space after the ending word "e". You can use product.strip to remove the spaces.

The second line, that is nil, is the of the EMOJI_STORE print, I Don't know why its nil